# Elastic Load Balancer and Varnish on Each Node

Tags: varnish, apache-2.4, amazon-elb

We want to install Varnish on our nodes that are handled by an Auto-Scaling Group and ELB.  These servers currently grow and contract based on load from 2-10 nodes.  We do not want to have another "master" varnish server due to cost implications.

Our optimal diagram would look like this:

```
           ELB
          / | \
Node 1 - Node 2 - Node 3, etc.
  |         |        |
Varnish  Varnish  Varnish
  |         |        |
Apache   Apache   Apache
  |         |        |
Centralized MySQL/File Servers
```

For further understanding, Varnish would be running on each of the Nodes as if all three are separate.

How do we keep all the Varnish's in-sync especially involving cache events (for example, someone updates a post on WordPress, and WordPress purges one of the Varnish caches but not the other 2).  I would rather not add another dedicated Varnish server to oversee all of this.  How do you normally handle the 3 varnish instances syncing across each other?  Is there something I am not thinking of correctly or an alternative configuration?

Answer (score 0):

usually we have some single admin server, with wordpress or magento running, they have special varnish plugin built into, it has all the logic, and sending commands to **varnishadm** on every server. or you can do the same from your workers, depends on your application.

```
           ELB
          / | \
Node 1 - Node 2 - Node 3, etc.
  |         |        |
Varnish  Varnish  Varnish
  |         |        |
Apache   Apache   Apache
  \         |        /
    Master Admin Node
   \        |       /
Centralized MySQL/File Servers
```

Comment: Lets say theoretically I put the master admin node on one of the file servers, but do I need to make changes to every wordpress or magneto site running.  We are a Private Shared host, with nearly a hundred sites.  Are these code changes?  If not, can you post an idea of what your config (or I suppose a script) looks like for this for the clients and the server?

Comment: google for: "wordpress purge multiple varnish servers", i guess you can easily create your own plugin/modification.

Comment: Wow ok, this seems extremely time consuming, and we would have to also make a plugin for other platforms we use.  I understand the concept, I wonder if there is a way to have all varnish purge requests get forwarded at the operating system level to a master server, then replicated back to all the different hosts...